# How do I not display "0" when printing my array?

Tags: c#

So this is my code currently:

```
string userInput;
        int userInputInt;
        int count = 0;
        int arrayLength;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter an Integer or a non integer value");

int[] userInputs;
        userInputs = new int[10];
        arrayLength = userInputs.Length;

        while (count < 10)
        {
            Console.Write("Please Enter the Next Number ");
            userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            if (int.TryParse(userInput, out userInputInt))
            {
                userInputs[count] = userInputInt;
                count = count + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        Array.Reverse(userInputs);
        foreach (var item in userInputs)
        {
            Console.Write(item.ToString() + " ");
```

When I print my array it displays the numbers entered by the user, but also a 0 in each space when the condition is broken and the rest of the array is not filled.

If the user enters : 1, 2, 3, q
How do I display: 3 2 1
Right now I get: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 2 1

Comment: Use `List<int>`.

Comment: You are inserting 3 values in a 10-element array. The other 7 will still be 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must use an array (rather than a `List` or `Stack` - which have the benefit of not being a fixed size like an array) I would suggest changing:

```
foreach (var item in userInputs)
```

to:

```
foreach (var item in userInputs.Where(z => z != 0))
```

to filter out the 0 values.

If 0 is a valid input, then consider changing:

```
int[] userInputs;
```

to:

```
int?[] userInputs;
```

and then using:

```
foreach (var item in userInputs.Where(z => z != null))
```

Comment: true... but 0 is a valid user input value.. which is why using List<int> is a better option

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not to take a fixed-size array, but a dynamically growing list:

```
string userInput;
int userInputInt;
int count = 0;
int arrayLength;
Console.WriteLine("Enter an Integer or a non integer value");

List<int>userInputs = new List<int>();
while (count < 10)
{
    Console.Write("Please Enter the Next Number ");
    userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    if (int.TryParse(userInput, out userInputInt))
    {
        userInputs.Add(userInputInt);
        count = count + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

This way you add only as many numbers as the user actually entered, but at max. 10.

Now loop your list:

```
foreach(var e in userInputs.Reverse()) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to use List instead for array, since the number of inputs are unknown/dynamic, So I prefer you to use List instead for int[].

```
List<int> userInputs = new List<int>
while (count < 10)
{
     Console.Write("Please Enter the Next Number ");
     userInput = Console.ReadLine();
     if (int.TryParse(userInput, out userInputInt))
     {
            userInputs.Add(userInputInt);
            count = count + 1;
     }
     else
     {
         break;
     }
}
```

And for printing items in reverse order you can use loop like the following:

```
for(int i=userInputs.Count-1;i>=0;i--)
{
    Console.Write(userInputs[i].ToString() + " ");
}
```

Or simply like [this Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8Qpk0O)

```
userInputs.Reverse();       
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",userInputs));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several options.
You could change the `foreach` loop to:

```
foreach (var item in userInputs.Take(count).Reverse())
```

or do it in one statement:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", userInputs.Take(count).Reverse()));
```

or use a `List<int>`, like others have said.

Answer (score 0):

Because the default value for the integer is 0, so when user enters only 3 items then he presses enter the loop will break and you will print the values along with the default, and worse you will not differentiate between zero from user or default value , I suggest using List instead and then add only the valid values entered by the user, like the following :

```
List<int> userInputs = new list<int>();
while (count < 10)
    {
        Console.Write("Please Enter the Next Number ");
        userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        if (int.TryParse(userInput, out userInputInt))
        {
            userInputs.Add(userInputInt);

        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
```